# is this facebook support jsoncallback=? (JSONP)

Tags: jquery, facebook, json, jsonp

```
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=397319800348866&format=jsoncallback=?
```

I want to get the post content via [here](https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=397319800348866&format=json) 
But I was try using getJSON method. It is not working through. Someone has told me to use jsonp format in the Facebook but when I go thought that URL it says the format is not supported. So is there any way to access without Cross domain problem?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the ampersand.

```
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=397319800348866&format=json&callback=?
```